# ipython notebookを起動しようとするとコマンドプロントが止まらない

Tags: python, anaconda

windows10でAnacondaをインストールして、コマンドプロンプトでipython notebookを起動しようとしたら、コマンドプロンプトの処理が延々と続いてしまいます。ipython notebookは起動しており使える状態なのですが。
何か分かる方がいれば教えてください。

[image: コマンドプロンプト画面]

Comment: ログレベルが `DEBUG` に設定されているのではないでしょうか。コマンドラインでオプションスイッチに `--log-level=CRITICAL` を追加するか、`ipython create profile` の実行によって生成される  `ipython_config.py` に `c.NotebookApp.log_level = CRITICAL` を追加すると良いかもしれません。

Comment: 早速のご回答ありがとうございます。素人なのでよく分かりませんが調べて試してみます。

Comment: ipython --log-level=CRITICALと入力すると正常に起動できました。ありがとうございます。ただ、毎回--log-level=CRITICALと入力しないと正常に起動できません。どこかに設定を保存できないのでしょうか？ipython_config.pyにはc.NotebookApp.log_level = CRITICALを追加しましたが変わりませんでした。

Comment: こちらの環境が Linux なので Windows 版でも当てはまるのかどうか分かりませんが、まず、`ipython notebook --generate-config` を実行してみて下さい。実行後、`~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` というファイルが作成されているかと思います。この `jupyter_notebook_config.py` に `c.Application.log_level = 50` を追加して下さい(`50` が `CRITICAL` に相当します)。

Comment: 教えて頂いた通りにしたら解決できました！ありがとうございました^^

Answer (score 1):

コメントで解決されたようですので、回答として編集・転記いたします。

#### コマンドラインオプションによる解決法

ログレベルが DEBUG に設定されている場合、コマンドラインでオプションスイッチに `--log-level=CRITICAL` を追加してみてください。

`> ipython --log-level=CRITICAL`

#### 設定変更による解決法

> (コマンドラインのオプションスイッチでは)毎回`--log-level=CRITICAL`と入力しないと正常に起動できません。
> どこかに設定を保存できないのでしょうか？

まず、`ipython notebook --generate-config` を実行してみて下さい。
実行後、`~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` というファイルが作成されているかと思います。
この jupyter_notebook_config.py に `c.Application.log_level = 50` を追加して下さい(50 が CRITICAL に相当します)。